# array.slice() to copy a new array

Tags: javascript

```
var arr  = [ ['hello', 'and', 'hi'], [2,3,4] ],
    arr2 = arr.slice();
arr2[1].push(44);
arr[0] = "new value";

console.log(arr, arr2);

//["new value", [2, 3, 4, 44]]
//[["hello", "and", "hi"], [2, 3, 4, 44]]
```

Isn't `arr2 = arr.slice()` supposed to create a new copy of `arr`? Therefore, `arr2[1].push(44)` won't effect the original `arr`

Can anyone tell me why the console logged arr has number 44 in its second element?

Comment: It copies the new array with the same elements.

Comment: Because you copy only parent array, you  also need copy all child arrays too, like this https://jsfiddle.net/o96hL8L9/2/

Comment: [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) : The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

So it's a desired behaviour - you have copied a reference to the second array so it has been changed in both `arr` and `arr2` variables.